# zf2 routing constraints use of wildcards / operators

Tags: php, routes, zend-framework2

I have read the ZF2 documentation [zend.mvc.routing](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html) and I see the following example used very often: 
What are the asterix * and the + sings doing behind the following constraints '[0-9]+' and '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*'?

```
return array(
  'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
      'blog' => array(
        'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
        'options' => array(
          'route'    => '/blog',
        ),
        'may_terminate' => true,
        'child_routes' => array(
          'post'  => array(
            'type' => 'Segment',
            'options' => array(
              'route'    => '/:category/page[/:page]',
              'constraints' => array(
                'category' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                'page'     => '[0-9]+',
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are regular expressions, you'll find a lot of documentation about it online.

The two specific characters have the following meaning:

- `*` - quantifier, means that the token it follows might appear 0 or more time
- `+` - same as `*` but means 1 or more time

The `[...]` expressions are character classes.

- `[0-9]` stands for any one character that is a number
- `[a-zA-Z]` stands for any any one character that is a lower or upper case letter

You can combine these character classes as you see in `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]` that is either a letter, a number , an underscore or a hyphen.

Also you can combine the character class with the quantifier:

- `[0-9]+` means one or more number
- `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*` means one lower or upper case letter followed by any number of letters, numbers, `_` or `-`

Comment: even a better answer then I hoped for